# Handle special chars

Tags: c#, stream, webclient

When I do

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string content = wc.DownloadString(url);
File.WriteAllText(path, content);
```

And I open the file in `path` with Internet Explorer, special characters like *ó* apear like *Ã³*.

Is there a way for interpreting correctly those characters?

Comment: When you open the file with text editor rather than browser, is it OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're downloading it in whatever content encoding is specified, but then *saving* it as UTF-8. If you want to save it to disk anyway, I suggest you use [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) directly instead. Then so long as the encoding is *also* specified in the HTML (correctly) it should be okay.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly now. I will check the encoding property. Thanks Jon.